# Intellij Live template populate a map with constants and values

Tags: java, intellij-idea, live-templates

I have Java interface with many constants. In some other class I must put all these constants with some values in a Map as follows:

```
properties.put(Constants.FIRST, value);
properties.put(Constants.SECOND, value2);
properties.put(Constants.ANOTHER, value3);
properties.put(Constants.ANOTHER2, value4);
properties.put(Constants.CUSTOM, value5);
```

How this can be achieved with Intellij Live template?

Comment: Sounds like a terrible design.  I hate putting constants in interfaces.  Better to keep them with the class that needs them.  You can do it with a custom template, but I wouldn't.

Comment: In matter of fact they are. The class implements the interface. What's the way with custom template to make this done? Thanks!

Comment: If that interface doesn't have methods I'd consider it a code smell.  Here's how you create custom templates: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/10/high-speed-coding-with-custom-live-templates/

Comment: I will consider removing these interfaces. Thanks. I take a look on some examples of custom templates, but I think there no way to iterate class constants, fields, right?

Comment: Have you considered an enum rather than series of constants? That way you get the benefits of constant-like behaviour, but can also assign more values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live templates provide no control structures yet, and thus, unfortunately, no way of iterating class fields. A small custom plugin would be needed.